# How to divide a pandas dataframe by a subsection of itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

While trying to divide all of the float columns in my dataframe by a predesignated slice of those same columns, I am returned with the correct values until I try to link my indices to the parent dataframe. Can you help me find a way properly index by time?

Thanks to some help on this forum the lamda function to divide the dataframe works well, but seems to change after I try to set the index.

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
        Time Well       1       2       3       4
0    0:00:00    A  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
1    0:00:00    B  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
2    0:00:00    C  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
3    0:00:00    D  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
4    0:00:00    E  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
5    0:00:00    F  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
6    0:00:00    G  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
7    0:00:00    H  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
8    0:00:14    A  0.0002  0.0014  0.0001 -0.0017
9    0:00:14    B  0.0024 -0.0020 -0.0016 -0.0006
10   0:00:14    C  0.0027  0.0018  0.0003  0.0024
11   0:00:14    D  0.0019  0.0019  0.0025  0.0013
12   0:00:14    E  0.0024  0.0021  0.0012  0.0005
13   0:00:14    F  0.0017  0.0015 -0.0003  0.0006
14   0:00:14    G  0.0003  0.0001  0.0001 -0.0017
15   0:00:14    H  0.0003 -0.0006 -0.0008 -0.0001
16   1:24:16    A  0.0293  0.0533  0.0223  0.0131
17   1:24:16    B  0.0295  0.0268  0.0200  0.0079
18   1:24:16    C  0.0373  0.0381  0.0165  0.0198
19   1:24:16    D  0.0327  0.0277  0.0282  0.0162
20   1:24:16    E  0.0400  0.0339  0.0234  0.0186
21   1:24:16    F  0.0270  0.0298  0.0141  0.0150
22   1:24:16    G  0.0215  0.0176  0.0114  0.0163
23   1:24:16    H  0.0251  0.0166  0.0292  0.0287
24  10:09:43    A  0.5072  0.6620  0.5092  0.5133
25  10:09:43    B  0.6089  0.5283  0.5426  0.4787
26  10:09:43    C  0.6340  0.6379  0.5221  0.5884
27  10:09:43    D  0.6167  0.5926  0.5856  0.5639
28  10:09:43    E  0.6512  0.6605  0.5561  0.5234
29  10:09:43    F  0.6168  0.6490  0.5577  0.5390
30  10:09:43    G  0.6312  0.5739  0.5221  0.5121
31  10:09:43    H  0.5123  0.5036  0.5052  0.4465

#### Current Output Received ##### 
test = df.groupby('Time').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:,2:6].reset_index(drop=True)/df[df['Time']=='1:24:16'].iloc[:,2:6].reset_index(drop=True))

In [20]: test
Out[20]: 
                    1          2          3          4
Time                                                  
0:00:00  0   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         1   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         2   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         3   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         4   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         5   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         6   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         7   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0:00:14  0   0.006826   0.026266   0.004484  -0.129771
         1   0.081356  -0.074627  -0.080000  -0.075949
         2   0.072386   0.047244   0.018182   0.121212
         3   0.058104   0.068592   0.088652   0.080247
         4   0.060000   0.061947   0.051282   0.026882
         5   0.062963   0.050336  -0.021277   0.040000
         6   0.013953   0.005682   0.008772  -0.104294
         7   0.011952  -0.036145  -0.027397  -0.003484
10:09:43 0  17.310580  12.420263  22.834081  39.183206
         1  20.640678  19.712687  27.130000  60.594937
         2  16.997319  16.742782  31.642424  29.717172
         3  18.859327  21.393502  20.765957  34.808642
         4  16.280000  19.483776  23.764957  28.139785
         5  22.844444  21.778523  39.553191  35.933333
         6  29.358140  32.607955  45.798246  31.417178
         7  20.410359  30.337349  17.301370  15.557491
1:24:16  0   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         1   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         2   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         3   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         4   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         5   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         6   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         7   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000

#### Now attemting to adjust the index ####
test.index = df.set_index(['Time','Well']).index

In [22]: test
Out[22]: 
                       1          2          3          4
Time     Well                                            
0:00:00  A      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         B      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         C      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         D      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         E      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         F      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         G      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
         H      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
0:00:14  A      0.006826   0.026266   0.004484  -0.129771
         B      0.081356  -0.074627  -0.080000  -0.075949
         C      0.072386   0.047244   0.018182   0.121212
         D      0.058104   0.068592   0.088652   0.080247
         E      0.060000   0.061947   0.051282   0.026882
         F      0.062963   0.050336  -0.021277   0.040000
         G      0.013953   0.005682   0.008772  -0.104294
         H      0.011952  -0.036145  -0.027397  -0.003484
1:24:16  A     17.310580  12.420263  22.834081  39.183206
         B     20.640678  19.712687  27.130000  60.594937
         C     16.997319  16.742782  31.642424  29.717172
         D     18.859327  21.393502  20.765957  34.808642
         E     16.280000  19.483776  23.764957  28.139785
         F     22.844444  21.778523  39.553191  35.933333
         G     29.358140  32.607955  45.798246  31.417178
         H     20.410359  30.337349  17.301370  15.557491
10:09:43 A      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         B      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         C      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         D      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         E      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         F      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         G      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
         H      1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000

#### My oversimplified approach to re-introduce 'Time' and 'Well' only puts 
#in nan values.
test[['Time', 'Well']] = df[['Time','Well']]
```

As you can see the matrix of 1's moved from time = 1:24:16 to time = 10:09:43. I am hoping to find a way to properly index by time, or at least a means to have the corect information to 'Time' and 'Well' columns in the newly divided dataframe.

Comment: what is the groupby ment for? do you want each chunk of 8 rows to be divided by the next chunk?

Comment: The groupby is meant to organize data by time. No, I want each chunk of 8 rows divided by a single chosen chosen chunk of 8 rows. I am hoping to divide each chunk of 8 rows by the values associated with the time = 0:00:14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `reset_index(drop=True)` and then reassign the index of your output dataframe like so:

```
test = df.groupby('Time', sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:,2:6].reset_index(drop=True)/df[df['Time']=='0:00:14'].iloc[:,2:6].reset_index(drop=True))

test.index = df.set_index(['Time','Well']).index
```

Output:

```
                       1           2       3           4
Time    Well                                            
0:00:00 A       0.000000    0.000000    0.00   -0.000000
        B       0.000000   -0.000000   -0.00   -0.000000
        C       0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.000000
        D       0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.000000
        E       0.000000    0.000000    0.00    0.000000
        F       0.000000    0.000000   -0.00    0.000000
        G       0.000000    0.000000    0.00   -0.000000
        H       0.000000   -0.000000   -0.00   -0.000000
0:00:14 A       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        B       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        C       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        D       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        E       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        F       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        G       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
        H       1.000000    1.000000    1.00    1.000000
1:24:16 A     146.500000   38.071429  223.00   -7.705882
        B      12.291667  -13.400000  -12.50  -13.166667
        C      13.814815   21.166667   55.00    8.250000
        D      17.210526   14.578947   11.28   12.461538
        E      16.666667   16.142857   19.50   37.200000
        F      15.882353   19.866667  -47.00   25.000000
        G      71.666667  176.000000  114.00   -9.588235
        H      83.666667  -27.666667  -36.50 -287.000000
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks for the help. I am having small difficulties going into a bigger dataframe. The division still works great, but the index throws the 1 matrix into a different time slot than was stated. It looks like the new index is going from 0:00:14 to 10:09:43... and 1:54:17 to 20:08:34. I think this is showing that the new index is only taking the first value of "Time" into consideration. Do you know any way to properly index time?

Comment: Could you update your original post with the example where this occurs? It's a bit hard to understand from your comment.

Comment: That was even hard to describe without the example. I have updated my question and dataframe to hopefully better explain my index problem.

Comment: I see, sorry for the late reply. You just need to pass `sort=False` to your `groupby()` method. See my edit.